# Secure different types of unsecured applications by a reverse proxy

Tags: security, jwt, single-sign-on, keycloak, openresty

I'm currently working on a project with complex requirements and I do not feel comfortable with the solution I'm considering.

The main idea is to secure existing applications (which do not include security themselves) without modifying them. These applications are not accessible from outside and will be accessible only through a reverse proxy (OpenResty).

Users do not have access to all applications and the solution to identify users is Keycloak.

The main components are :

- An angular portal : the entry point
- A reverse proxy that redirect the user on the chosen application
- The IAM : Keycloak
- All the available application

[this schema explain it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GFPx.png)

The idea is :

- The user click sign in  on Keycloak and gets back to the portal with an access token (JWT) that contains his roles (application he has access to)
- The user click on an application on the portal and he is redirected to the targeted application through the reverse proxy
- The reverse proxy check the validity of the token (exp, iss and the roles)

I know this is not a proper way to do some SSO between application, but the requirement here is that the application, that are not secured can't be edited bu have to be protect by an upfront system (the reverse-proxy here)

My question is : ok this will work for the first call, because the user have his JWT token on the portal and hits the application with it the first time, but after when the user will click on a link in this app.. there is no more token. This kind of architecture works well to protect REST API bu for a web application, sounds to me a little incertain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you would have reverse proxy server to handle user authentication instead of login to keycloak first.

Flow will be like this:

1. User access portal.
2. Portal redirects user to application through reverse proxy.
3. The reverse proxy will first redirect user to keycloak for
   authentication, and build a security session between browser and
   reverse proxy server.
4. The reverse proxy forward request to your application
   server.
5. For all subsequent requests, user always go through reverse proxy server.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer, I understand why handle authentification in the reverse proxy.
But I need the user to be logged in on the portal as well in order to get his roles (that helps me to filter the apps he has access to)
. You talk about "build a security session between browser and reverse proxy server" is it about creating a cookie with a session ID ? Or is it about store the user token in a cookie ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [github.com/gambol99/keycloak-proxy](https://github.com/gambol99/keycloak-proxy). It stores token in the cookie, which is better option for web apps.

!!! Warning: I guess any auth proxy can use only *Authorization Code Flow*, however *Implicit Flow* is recommended for Single-Page Application (Angular). It really depends what's your Angular app. Analyze sec. pros and cons first, to be secure.

Comment: Thanks, To be precise Keycloak is able to do Implicit Flow as well as Authorization Code Flow.

Comment: Yes. My point is about the place of implementation. Authorization Code Flow => in the auth proxy, Implicit Flow => in the Angular.